# GLFW won't work with stereo rendering

Tags: c++, glfw, stereo-3d

**UPDATE**: In an effort to eliminate possible causes, I tried to run the [GLFW example code](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html#quick_example) with stereo 3D, adding a

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, GL_TRUE);
```

right before the

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
```

line. Runs fine without it. With it, I get this error message:

> GLX: Failed to find a suitable GLXFBConfig

Am I missing something?

**Original post**:

I'm trying to get my GLFW application working with stereo 3d. It works fine without stereo. Also, `glxgears -stereo` works fine, so it seems to be a problem with the application itself.

Here's the initialization code:

```
void InitRendering() {
    if(!glfwInit()) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwInit failed");
    }
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, GL_TRUE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, conf.supersampling);
    GLFWvidmode return_struct;
    glfwGetDesktopMode( &return_struct );
    if(!glfwOpenWindow(conf.fullscreen ? return_struct.Width : conf.screen_width, 
                       conf.fullscreen ? return_struct.Height : conf.screen_height,
               8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 
                       conf.fullscreen ? GLFW_FULLSCREEN : GLFW_WINDOW)) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwOpenWindow failed"); // This happens.
    }
    ...
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Both windowed and fullscreen.
- Turning off AA.
- Setting the bits in `glfwOpenWindow` to 5,6,5,0 instead of 8,8,8,8.

I've done all the stuff in `xorg.conf` to get `glxgears` to work with stereo (Stereo mode to 10, disable compositing). The card is an Nvidia Quadro 5000. If you need more info just say so and I'll add it.

Comment: If you run `glxinfo`, does it list any stereo-capable GLXFBConfigs?

Comment: `glxgears` seems to be using visuals instead of GLXFBConfigs, so it's possible your driver is providing stereo versions of one but not the other.